# Deleting files by pattern matching

Tags: shell, sh

How do I delete files of a particular pattern using shell scripting. For example, I need to remove all files that start with the prefix INPUT. I tried the command `rm INPUT*` in my shell script but it interprets `*` as a literal, so I get a file not found error.

Comment: It would only do that if you had it escaped or in quotes etc.

Comment: It sounds like there were no matching files, so the pattern `INPUT*` was passed as-is to `rm`.

Comment: probable debug step: does `ls INPUT*` give any output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `eval "rm INPUT*"` ....

Answer (score 0):

The command `rm INPUT*` is almost what you want, but it generates an error if no files exist that match the pattern.  The shell attempts to expand `INPUT*` to match filenames; if none match, it passes the literal string `INPUT*` to `rm` which correctly reports that no such file exists.  The simplest way to prevent seeing the error message is to add `-f`:

```
rm -f INPUT*
```